# Is Canvas.drawVertices TRIANGLES mode, only take first first 3 coordinate only, and ignore others?

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw, vertices

In `canvas.drawVertices(...)`, there's 3 modes. I.e. `Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES`, `Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES_FAN` and `Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES_STRIP`

I could understand [`Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES_FAN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_fan) and [`Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES_STRIP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip). But not `Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES`

Is it true that `Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES`, will also draw a triangle from the first 3 coordinate from the `verts` below, and ignore the others? i.e. it is ignoring the last 2 coordinates of `verts`, that is `{width/3f, height.toFloat(), 0f, height.toFloat()}`

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) return
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    val verts = floatArrayOf(
        0f, 0f,
        width.toFloat(), 0f,
        width/2f, height.toFloat(),
        width/3f, height.toFloat(),
        0f, height.toFloat()
    )

    canvas.drawVertices(Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES, verts.size, verts, 0,
        null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, 0, paint)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for `TRIANGLES`, it needs coordinate of 3x e.g., 3, 6, 9, 12...  So that each 3 set of coordinates will be drawn as a triangle.

E.g. using the below `verts` would draw the 2 triangles.

```
    val verts = floatArrayOf(
        0f, 0f,
        width.toFloat(), 0f,
        width/2f, height.toFloat(),
        width/3f, height.toFloat(),
        10f, height.toFloat() - 10f,
        10f, 10f
    )
```